# ReleaseCumulativeFlowData and CardState

Tags: rally

I'm trying to run a query against the ReleaseCumulativeFlowData object as follows:

```
((ReleaseObjectID = 12345) AND CardState="Accepted")
```

However, running the query results in the following error message:

```
OperationResultError
Could not read: could not read all instances of class
com.f4tech.slm.domain.reporting.ReleaseCumulativeFlowDataSet
```

Is this a bug in Rally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WSAPI is very picky about the structure of the query. You have to include parentheses around chained query filters, so you would need something like the following:

> ((ReleaseObjectID = 12345) AND (CardState = "Accepted"))

Comment: No, that's not it. That markup is malformed; it returns the error: OperationResultError Could not parse: Unknown operator ")"

Anyone else have an idea what that original error is all about?

Comment: Actually, what you have is correct if you add spaces around the = sign in the second condition. Boy is Rally finicky...

Comment: Haha, sorry about that. I guess I should've added those. Not sure why I left it like that. Let me change it now.